# last div box not equally spaced on the margin-right

Tags: css, html, jsfiddle

I have a bunch of divs inside a container that is equally spaced from the right as well as from the bottom. (i.e margin-right and margin-bottom are the same)
Here is my jsfiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/wYCzJ/1/
Here is my css code:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
   position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;

}

.box {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color:#DDD;
  padding: 0.5em;
  height: 150px;
}


.name{
  width: 95%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.result {
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
}
.result-type {
  float:left;
  display:inline;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: inline;
}

.result-value {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline;
}

.no_data {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: darkgray;
}

.date {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  color: gray;
}
```

Everything works fine as expected, except that the last div box has extra some extra spacing towards the right ( Test 5 box and Test 7 box in this case)
I kinda need the same spacing all around. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: CSS are not enough for us to help, we need your HTML too!

Comment: there is a jsfiddle link I have posted in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

you will have only 5px from the right

it's up to you to make div container to margin 5px from left and top

---

i managed to twick it:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

tested it in Chrome and FF - http://jsfiddle.net/elen/wYCzJ/3/

---

found and adopted this version - jsfiddle.net/elen/5CJ5e/131 - see if it works for you
please notice combination of `text-align: justify;`, `font-size: 0;` and heights for both outer and inner boxes. also use of `<span class="stretch"></span>` for 100% width

Comment: Thanks. But If I do that there Test 6 and test 6 boxes start from extreme left which I dont want.http://jsfiddle.net/wYCzJ/2/ . I want it to be eqaully spaced from top,left,right,bottom

Comment: it works in the jsfiddle. But the part of the code i posted resides inside other divs. When I try out your code the whole page moves towards the left and it doesnt help with the spacing too. I ll try to see if I can post the whole stuff on js fiddle.

Comment: as i was going to say - unfortunately i could never find definitive solution for something like this. every time i had to work around depending on content... so yes. try to post as much code as possible, lets have a look

Comment: i found and adopted this fiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/elen/5CJ5e/131/ - see if you can work around with this one

Comment: thanks. i ll try out out a combination of your methods and see! Can you post your jsfiddle link in your answer. I ll accept it after i try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your probleme is simple, the body have a natural margin.

```
body{margin-right:0px}
```

That solve your probleme, but it's a bit wierd to have a bodywith only the `margin-right` at 0...

Answer (score 0):

The overall container has spacing for its top, bottom, left, and right.  Your individual boxes only have spacing on the bottom and right.  The reason you are seeing "extra" spacing on the right is because the spacing for the individual box and the overall container are being added together.

Answer (score 0):

A possible sollution with `nth-child`. This removes the margin of every 4th `.box` element.

```
.wrapper:nth-child(4n) .box{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wYCzJ/5/

Have a look at [browser support of nth-child at caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3).